# Magento 2 Catalog rule can not applied after reindex automatic

Tags: magento2

I wrote the code for creating a Catalog rule in Magento 2.3.5 and after saving I have the code to re-index it automatically.

```
  /** @var \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule $model */
            $ruleRepository = $this->_objectManager->get(
                \Magento\CatalogRule\Api\CatalogRuleRepositoryInterface::class
            );
            $catalogRule = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule::class);
            $ruleByBoRefId = $this->getRuleByBoRefId($boRefId);
            if (isset($ruleByBoRefId["rule_id"]) && $ruleId = $ruleByBoRefId["rule_id"]) {
                $catalogRule = $ruleRepository->get($ruleId);
            }

            $catalogRule->loadPost($catalogRuleData);
            //$catalogRule->save();
            $ruleRepository->save($catalogRule);
            $this->reindexCatalogRule($catalogRule);
```

Code Reindex:

```
public function reindexCatalogRule($catalogRule){

if($catalogRule->isRuleBehaviorChanged()){
    $this->_objectManager
        ->create(\Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Flag::class)
        ->loadSelf()
        ->setState(0)
        ->save();
}

$collection = $this->_indexerCollectionFactory->create()->getAllIds();
foreach ($collection as $id) {
    $indexer = $this->_indexerFactory->create()->load($id);
    $indexer->getState()
        ->setStatus(\Magento\Framework\Indexer\StateInterface::STATUS_INVALID)
        ->save();
    $indexer->reindexAll();
}
```

}

But after reindex the Rule still doesn't apply to the product. However, after I go to the admin and edited the previously saved catalog rule => Click Save => Then I ran the Indexer: reindex command of magento, the rule applies normally.
I don't understand why like that. Please help me How to apply rules to products automatically ? Thanks